# How Kafka producer find the schema Id for a record

Tags: java, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry

In Kafka producer I can see we only need to specify the schema registry url and not the schema I'd. So while serialisation of records how producer decide which schema to use. Because schema registry can host a number of schema.

https://dzone.com/articles/kafka-avro-serialization-and-the-schema-registry

see below example given in above url. here i dont see schema id but only registry url. then how producer find the correct schema?

public class AvroProducer {

```
private static Producer<Long, Employee> createProducer() {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, "AvroProducer");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
            LongSerializer.class.getName());

    // Configure the KafkaAvroSerializer.
   props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
            KafkaAvroSerializer.class.getName());

    // Schema Registry location.
    props.put(KafkaAvroSerializerConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG,
            "http://localhost:8081");

    return new KafkaProducer<>(props);
}

private final static String TOPIC = "new-employees";

public static void main(String... args) {

    Producer<Long, Employee> producer = createProducer();

    Employee bob = Employee.newBuilder().setAge(35)
            .setFirstName("Bob")
            .setLastName("Jones")
            .setPhoneNumber(
                    PhoneNumber.newBuilder()
                            .setAreaCode("301")
                            .setCountryCode("1")
                            .setPrefix("555")
                            .setNumber("1234")
                            .build())
            .build();

    IntStream.range(1, 100).forEach(index->{
        producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>(TOPIC, 1L * index, bob));

    });

    producer.flush();
    producer.close();
}
```

}

Comment: Do you have any example code?

Answer (score 1):

The POJO class you're sending gets serialized to include the schema, which is sent as plaintext to the Registry before your binary data payload is sent to Kafka.

When the registry HTTP request is received on the server-side it uses MD5 hash against a few internal Hashmaps to check/insert the schema-text hash alongside the topic/Avro record (Registry "subject") name, then returns the numeric ID back to the serializer in an HTTP response to create the Kafka message payload.

The Schema Registry code is open source if you want to learn more

Answer (score 0):

There are three modes of how a schema can be *connected* to a message:

- **default** is via the topic name (all messages in the topic share the same schema) (TopicNameStrategy)
- via the message/record type (all message types get the same schema regardless of the topic) (RecordNameStrategy)
- via the message/record type end the topic name (TopicRecordNameStrategy)

So the producer determines based on the configured strategy which schema to lookup and fetch from the schema registry. It will validate the payload, serialize it and store the schema id in the first 4 bytes.

See bottem section: https://www.confluent.io/blog/put-several-event-types-kafka-topic/

Answer (score 0):

To know the schema ID in the Registry of a message the producer first needs to know what the schema of the message looks like, to do so at least with the Java Avro's serializer the producer makes use of reflection to get the schema description which it then uses to request its id in the Registry.

The Schema Registry code is open source so you can see that the logic I mention looks something like [this](https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/master/avro-serializer/src/main/java/io/confluent/kafka/serializers/KafkaAvroSerializer.java):

```
 @Override
  public byte[] serialize(String topic, Headers headers, Object record) {
    if (record == null) {
      return null;
    }
    AvroSchema schema = new AvroSchema(
        AvroSchemaUtils.getSchema(record, useSchemaReflection,
            avroReflectionAllowNull, removeJavaProperties));
    return serializeImpl(
        getSubjectName(topic, isKey, record, schema), topic, headers, record, schema);
  }
```

And once generated the schema is kept in cache, so if the schema extracted locally from the message object class that is about to be sent is not present in memory it is computed and [saved in the cache](https://github.com/apache/avro/blob/master/lang/java/avro/src/main/java/org/apache/avro/specific/SpecificData.java) to prevent future reprocessing.

```
private final ClassValueCache<Schema> schemaClassCache = new ClassValueCache<>(c -> createSchema(c, new HashMap<>()));

/** Find the schema for a Java type. */
  public Schema getSchema(java.lang.reflect.Type type) {
    try {
      if (type instanceof Class) {
        return schemaClassCache.apply((Class<?>) type);
      }
      return schemaTypeCache.computeIfAbsent(type, t -> createSchema(t, new HashMap<>()));
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw (e instanceof AvroRuntimeException) ? (AvroRuntimeException) e : new AvroRuntimeException(e);
    }
  }
```

Having the schema definition the producer can use it to get the corresponding ID or can throw an error as the following in case the given schema doesn't exist inside the Registry

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error retrieving Avro schema 
Caused by:io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException:Subject not found.; error code: 40401\n\tat
```